# Looping over users and their loggedin dates and merging data sets

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to build some dashboard components - and I want to loop over the data to get a total login count per day over all the users.

code would look something like this - but need to set flags to chop the count when the date (day) changes

```js
let people = [{
    "loginHistory": ["2023-04-25T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-26T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-26T18:04:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-27T18:00:54.205+00:00"]
  },
  {
    "loginHistory": ["2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-25T18:04:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-27T18:00:54.205+00:00"]
  }
]

//array of people -- with an array of login datestamps


//loop through the users and get a date/count 

let userDateValues = [];
let dateValues = [];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; ++i) {
  let loginHistory = people[i].loginHistory;
  //sort array by date
  if (loginHistory) {
    for (let j = 0; j < loginHistory.length; ++j) {
      console.log("loginHistory[j]", loginHistory[j]);
    }
  }

  //flags to cut/count the logins per day for this user
  let dateValue = {
    "date": moment(), //unique day
    "value": 10
  }
  dateValues.push(dateValue);

  //add data to array
  userDateValues.push(dateValues);
}

console.log("dateValues", dateValues);
console.log("userDateValues", userDateValues);

//want to then merge ALL the counts per same day - so find out how many times ALL users had logged in each day

/*    
[{
    "date": moment(),
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "date": moment().add(1, 'days'),
    "value": 612
  }, {
    "date": moment().add(2, 'days'),
    "value": 23
  }, {
    "date": moment().add(3, 'days'),
    "value": 23
  }]
*/
```

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the dates.

Comment: well - the structure I have shown is more close to how it is being stored/fetching from the db

Comment: I know. I'm telling you how to structure the data that you're going to transform it into, to get the per-day counts.

Comment: an object whose keys are the dates -- but its just an array of date stamps.

Comment: What he means is is that you can loop over the array and transform it into an object. In the loop check if a day (key) exists. If it does, then add 1, if it doesn't then add the day to the object and set it to 1. This way you can count the occurrences of each day in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not a huge table, I would go for the following approach which is not very efficient, but its quite simple and readable.

1. "flat" all the dates to one array with only the dates
2. using a loop, create an object where the key is the day (not the timestamp, only the day part) and the value is how many occurrences exist
3. convert the object to an array like you wanted. (array of {Date, Count})
4. sort the array by day

```js
let people = [{
    "loginHistory": ["2023-04-25T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-26T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-26T18:04:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-27T18:00:54.205+00:00"]
  },
  {
    "loginHistory": ["2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-25T18:04:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-27T18:00:54.205+00:00"]
  },
  {
    "loginHistory": ["2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-22T18:00:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-25T18:04:54.205+00:00", "2023-04-27T18:00:54.205+00:00"]
  }
];

//flat all the dates to one array
const timestamps = people.flatMap(_ => _.loginHistory);

//count the occurences of each date in a dictionary structure
const day2count = {};
timestamps.forEach(timestamp => {
    const day = timestamp.split('T')[0];
    day2count[day] = (day2count[day] || 0) + 1;
});
   
// convert the map to an array of entries

const result = Object.entries(day2count).map(([date, count]) => ({Date: date, Count: count }))
    // The date format is already sortable, so we can just sort the entries by key
    .sort((a, b) => a.Date.localeCompare(b.Date))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you - works well - I appreciate the data set structure seemed awkward. Its more of an internal admin insights

Comment: Happy to hear that ! 
Its actually a typical data transformation task, if you have many of these I suggest to get acquainted with methods like "map", "reduce" and similar functions which can greatly simplify your work and prevent bugs.

Comment: I got a lot of examples of it -- but late at night - wanting to work on something else - I knew someone would enjoy a silly puzzle like this. I was focusing more on what data I had and how it could be used and what it could look like.